# One element above second in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a small problem with my layout.
This is code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/popuplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_choose_language_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/popup_andr"
            android:text="@string/login_choose_language_txt" 
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_choose_language_txt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="@drawable/background_gray_9patch"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_language_1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pl" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_language_2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pl"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_language_3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pl"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_language_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pl"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is because layout which has imageViews cover part of my button. I know that I have marginTop because I need to put top of this layout under this button, but I want to hide this part from top under button. How I can do to button was above layout?

Comment: Add  **android:layout_below="@+id/login_choose_language_txt"** in your Relative Layout.

Comment: Do what Numair said, and your root-LinearLayout is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:layout_below="@+id/login_choose_language_txt"` to your Button tag.